# Cannot reinitialize datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

Hi I'm having the below code where I load the datatable on a click of the button

```
$("#search").click(function () {
         // alert("Video inside");
        
            //$("#Video_Details").dataTable().fnDestroy();
          console.log(lat);
          $("#Video_Details").DataTable({

            // // Ajax for api call
            ajax: {
              //   // api endpoint uri
              //urlString: "http://localhost:8080/xx/xx/xx/xx/xx",
              url: url,
              type: "GET",
              data: function (json) {
                console.log(json);
                return json;
              },
            },
```

When I click the second time I'm getting cannot reinitialize error. Can someone please clarify?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to use the DataTables [`retrieve`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/retrieve) option:

```
"retrieve": true
```

From the documentation:

> *if the table has already been initialised, this parameter will cause DataTables to simply return the object that has already been set up*

The reason you get this error is because the `DataTable( {...} )` function actually creates and initializes the DataTable - and you can only do this once for each table.

---

One alternative is to use the [`destroy`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/destroy) option - but that is a relatively expensive operation if you are not actually changing any of the initialization options each time you click your button.

---

Another alternative is to create and initialize the table outside of the button click, and assign it to a variable:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    ...
  } );

} );
```

Now you can use the `table` variable. This approach means that the table will be initialized and displayed *before* the first click of the button - which may not be what you want.